# Javascript continuous server polling

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, comet

I am going through the development of one web application on Java servlet technology, in which the client page is polling to server through javascript an AJAX request for new data after every 2 seconds.
The issue which i'm facing is that the server is getting slow because of regular polling of multiple prallel clients.

So is there any other alternative to achieve this functionality automatically only after any other request is triggered to the server that updates the data on server.

I am trying to use javascript comet but not getting the proper code for implementation.

Any help would be appreciable.

Regards,
Ars

Comment: How exactly are you doing the polling? What happens on the server side each time you hit it with your ajax request?

Comment: @JamieDixon when my jsp is loading, then i'm sending the ajax request through javascript function, by the line `xmlhttp.open("GET","gettime",true); //gettime will be the servlet name xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getVal;` 
getVal is the javasrcipt method in which i'm taking the XML format data coming from the servlet, after that i'm parsing the data by `xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("ABCD");` and utilizing it.
And getVal has setTimeout(methodname,2000); which is executing it regularly after every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Servlet 3.0 will be good solution for yoour needs.

It will release your thread while your request is executing
You can read more about here. in the article below:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html

In addition I would recommend you to look at [Atmosphere Framework](http://atmosphere.java.net/) and [Netty framework](http://netty.io/)

Those frameworks can give you not bad alternative to standard Servlet container if chasing rapid Comet implementation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you should use comet approach. You can try to use [socket.io](http://socket.io). There are several Java implementations of this protocol like [socketio-java](http://code.google.com/p/socketio-java/) and [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio). You will be able to cover a larger set of browsers than using WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

Use [websockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets) to connect your server with the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the perfect opportunity for you to start websockets. That was made for purposes like this.
[WebSocket - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

[WebSocket Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm)

[WebSocket API Guide](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/)

If you would like to code the server application in a different language as well , the you can easily google websocket tutorials for that language to help you out